# Bootstrap popover on moving elements

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, popover

I am trying to use a static popover on an element whose position may change by accordion. However the popover stays at the same place when accordion is activated. How can I enable popover to change its position accordingly ?

Here is the related code:

(on JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gordianknot/VLmNM/1/ you may click any section for instance)

HTML:

```
    <h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
    <div><p>Section 1 Content</p></div>

    <h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>
    <div><p>Section 2 Content</p></div>

    </div>
    <br/>
    <a id="example" name="example" href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Example Button</a>
```

JS:

```
    $(function() {
        $("#accordion").accordion({ 
           collapsible: true, 
            autoHeight: false, 
            active: false 

        });

        $("#example").popover({
         trigger:'manual',
         placement: 'right',
         html: 'true',
         title : 'Test',
         content : 'Hello !',

        });

        $('#example').popover('show');
    });
```

Comment: You should mention that you are using v2.0.4. Why not upgrade?

Comment: @davidkonrad I'm already using an updated version (just forgot to select it in jsfiddle). So this problem also persists in v3.1.1

Comment: _So this problem also persists in v3.1.1 _, I know, just thought it was too outdated, doubt 2.0.4 is even downloadable anymore :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it's not the most elegant solution, but it will do:

**JQuery:**

```
var hasMoved = false;
    $('#accordion').click(function () {
        if ($('#accordion').children('h3').hasClass('ui-state-active')) {


            if(!hasMoved) {
            $('.popover').animate({
                top: "+=60"
            }, 250);
              hasMoved = true;  
            }
        } else {
            $('.popover').animate({
                top: "-=60"
            } , 250);
            hasMoved = false; 
        }
    });

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VLmNM/7/)**

Comment: Yeah, although it's tied to the accordion it works :) Thank you

Comment: This is not a good solution because you have set the top offset statically. so can you tel me what happened if one of accordion elements has extra content !? see your demo with some extra content http://jsfiddle.net/VLmNM/13/ or with adding new accordion item !

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution is `binding` `accordionchange`
and using `top` `offset` of `button's current position`.

```
$('#accordion').bind('accordionchange', 
function() {
   var element_height = $( "#example" ).height();
   $('.popover').animate({
            top: $( "#example" ).offset().top - element_height * 2
        } , 250);        
});
```

look at this [**Demo Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/VLmNM/16/)

Answer (score 0):

although this is really old and wont be seen, it serves as reference for others with this problem. By changing the trigger to hover it will only open when you hover, but your code means that it opens automatically. Again, this serves as reference to others with this problem and it is a simpler solution.